# Unauthorized user accesssing hidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba, hidden

A user that was once authorized is now unauthorized (I removed the user's name from the VBA code) but somehow this user is still able to access the hidden sheets in the modified version.

To test the code, I removed myself and my colleague as authorized users.  Once we were removed, we could not access the hidden sheets.  So the code seems to be working properly.  Here is sample:

```
Option Compare Text
Private Sub Workbook_Open()


Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden


Dim user As String
Dim users(41) As String

users(0) = "MCCARTHYJ"
users(1) = "krishnam
```

'and so on.... until the 41 users are named

```
user = Environ$("Username")

Dim access As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

access = False

For i = 0 To 40
    If users(i) = user Then
    Sheet9.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheet5.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("PLM Approval").Select
    Range("B4").Select
  Exit For

End If

End Sub
```

I can't understand how the user was able to access the hidden sheets if he was no longer a named user.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but Excel security should not be trusted. Anyone could enter the VB Editor and change those sheets' visibility. Even if you password-protected the VBA project, that password can be hacked...

Comment: Thanks, Big Ben.  I did password protect the VBA code and I do understand that there is a chance it could be hacked.   We have an example from the unauthorized user and I checked the VBA code, the user did not add themselves nor edit my code.   The user is not very tech savvy so it is very doubtful that it was hacked.    It's very strange....

Comment: Yeah I doubted that the user had, I just wanted to point out that you can't really trust this "security". Was the workbook reopened after you removed that user?

Comment: Thanks BigBen.  A new version of the file was created with the user's name omitted and this new version was sent to the user and when it was returned there was evidience that the user had access to the hidden sheet.   The user had made comments and actually overwrote some formulas.

Comment: Plain and simple - excel is not secure by itself. Between hex editors and other fun tricks people can get into it if they really want to

Comment: If your user just holds down Shift while opening the workbook then the Workbook_open will not run.

Comment: Anyone can unprotect a VBA project within seconds - minutes if they've never done it before. If you don't want a user to access a worksheet, given them access to a workbook that doesn't contain that worksheet.

Comment: Also environment variables can easily be spoofed.

Comment: Thank you everyone.   @MathieuGuindon, could a slow network connection cause the VBA code to fail?

Comment: As others have noted, VBA security will only keep honest people out.  Is your unauthorised user deliberately circumventing the security, or is it just not working?  If they are not actively working against you, sit down with them to see what they are doing differently.